# Sequelize - fetch data from database by timestamp with time zone

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

Am trying to fetch data from postgreSQL using sequelize where my current Date is equivelant to the timestamp with the time zone date in the dataBase

```
 const startDate = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    const endDate = new Date().setHours(24,60,60,60)
    return await this.accountRepository.findAll({  
       where: {
         '$accountHistory.createdAt$' : { $between: [startDate, endDate] },
       },
       include: [{
       model: AccountHistory,
       as: 'accountHistory',
       required: false
      }],              
      })
    }
```

Comment: It's better to indicate UTC date times because PostgreSQL anyway stores timestamps w/timezones as UTC.

Comment: Use something like 'date-fns'